# PHP MySQL not displaying all table rows

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm new to programming and web development and stuff so for fun I've created a database of all my blurays/DVDs and created an html page with php to connect to the mysql database and then somebody enters their name and selects a year and it displays all the movies from the that year of release.  This is all done locally. However, for some reason when its ran it does not display all rows.  Sometimes it pulls only 1 row, sometimes it pull 2 or 3 rows.  Just wondering if somebody can tell me what's wrong.  I have two .php files.  The form and the processor. The select statement I used works just fine in the MySQL console and displays all data correctly there.  Lastly, I know that CSS could be put to better use here with alignments and table borders, etc., but that's not what I'm focused on right now.

Form

```
<?php
//variables
$strHost = "localhost";
$strUser = "root";
$strPass = "";
$strDB = "movies";
$strYear = "";
$intYearMin = 1900;
$intYearMax = 2025;
$dblYearIncrement = 1;
$strYearOptions = "";
//populate dropdown list
for ($i=$intYearMin; $i<=$intYearMax; $i+=$dblYearIncrement) {
    $strYearOptions .= "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option> \n";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE hmtl>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Movie Listing: The Form</title>
        <!-- Link style sheet link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/styleDefault.css" /> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./movies.css" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function Start(){
                    document.getElementByID("txtName").focus();
            }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="Start();">
        <h1>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        My Movies <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <img src="./filmreel1.png" alt="Film Reel" width="68" height="60" />
        </h1>
        <h2> Movie listing by year: </h2>
        <form action="movies_1_proc.php" method="post" id="frmSale">
            <ul>
                <li>Your name: <input size="30" name="txtName" id="txtName" /></li>
                <li>
                        Year:
                        <select name="Year">
                            <option value="xxx">Choose . . . </option>
                <?php echo $strYearOptions; ?>
                        </select>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <p class="centered">
                <input type="submit" name="cmdSubmit" value="See What's Available" />
            </p>
        </form>
    <body>
<html>
```

Processor and displays results

```
<?php
//initialization
$strHost = "localhost";
$strUser = "root";
$strPass = "";
$strDB = "movies";
//get data from html form
$dblMaxYear = $_POST['Year'];
$strName = $_POST['txtName'];
$strTableBlock = "";
//build sql string based on form data
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE Year = $dblMaxYear ORDER BY IF(LEFT(title,2) = 'A ',
            SUBSTRING(title FROM 3),
            IF(LEFT(title,3) = 'An ',
              SUBSTRING(title FROM 4),
              IF(LEFT(title,4) = 'The ',
                 SUBSTRING(title FROM 5),
                 title)))";
//create dbms connection and open db
$strConn = mysqli_connect($strHost,$strUser,$strPass,$strDB);
//submit a query
$strResult= mysqli_query($strConn,$strSQL);
//process query
$arrRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($strResult);
/*echo "<br />$strResult<br />";*/
    while ($strRow = mysqli_fetch_array($strResult)) {
        $strYear = $strRow['Year'];
        $strRuntime = $strRow['Runtime'];
        $strTitle = $strRow['Title'];
        $strDirector = $strRow['Director'];
        $strFormat = $strRow['Format'];
        $strRating = $strRow['Rating'];
        $strGenre = $strRow['Genre'];
        $strRTscore = $strRow['RTscore'];
        $strTableBlock .= "
            <tr>
                <td>$strYear</td><td>$strTitle</td><td>$strDirector</td><td>$strRuntime</td><td>$strFormat</td><td>$strRating</td><td>$strGenre</td><td>$strRTscore</td>
            </tr> \n";
    }
//wrapup database processing
mysqli_free_result($strResult);
mysqli_close($strConn) or die("Crash");
//output formatting
$strMaxYear = $dblMaxYear;
?>

<!DOCTYPE hmtl>
<html xmlns="http://w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>My Movies Listing: The Processor</title>
        <!-- Link style sheet link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/styleDefault.css" /> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./movies.css" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <!--<style type="text/css">
            table{
                    //margin:auto;
                    margin-left:auto;
                    margin-right:auto;
                    background-color:white;
            }
            .rightaling{
                    text-align:right;
            }
        </style>-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 align = "center">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        My Movies <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <img src="./filmreel1.png" alt="Film Reel" width="68" height="60" />
        </h1>
        <h2 align = "center"> Movies From Year <?php echo $strMaxYear; ?> for <?php echo $strName; ?>:</h2>
        <table border="2" align="center">
            <tr><th>Year</th><th>Title</th><th>Director</th><th>Runtime</th><th>Format</th><th>Rating</th><th>Genre</th><th>RT%</th></tr>
            <?php echo $strTableBlock ?>
        </table>
    <body>
<html>
```

Comment: Check the following url
[mysqli_result::fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) **See Example #1 Object oriented style**

Comment: please learn how to use php alternative syntax to use https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php Also you don't need JavaScript start. Use <input autofocus />